# Spring JavaConfig + WebMvcConfigurerAdapter + @Autowired => NPE

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, configuration, autowired, objectmapper

I have an application with 2 Contexts. Parent for web agnostic business logic and ChildContext (implicitly created by dispatcher servlet) for web logic.

My setup loks like

```
@Configuration
public class BusinessConfig {
   @Bean 
   public ObjectMapper jacksonMapper() { return new ObjectMapper() } 
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper; // <- is null for some reason
    @Override
    public configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)    {
         MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
         converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper); // <- bang!
         messageConverters.add(converter);
    } 
}
```

I need the the object mapper in the parent context, as I use it also in security configuration. But can someone explain me, why the @Autowired objectMapper is null? Its created in the parent context (the fact that the parent exists is even logged by spring at startup). Also @Autowired has required=true by default, so it should not blow up in the configure method (it should have blown up in construction of the context, if the bean wasn't there for some reason).

It seems to me that there might be some lifecycle problem in spring - in a sense that it calls the overridden methods first, and then @Autowires the dependencies... I have also tried to @Autowire the BusinessConfig (should be perfectly legal according to documentation - the result was the same (null)).

What should I do to make this working?

Thanks in advance!

### **EDIT - ISSUE FOUND**

I found the issue. Unfortunately it had nothing to do with WebMvcConfigurerAdapter nor @Configuration. It was caused by premature initialization of context triggered by missing static modifier for propertyPlaceholderConfigurer... I have created issue in Spring core jira (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14382)

Comment: Actually spring child-parent relation works the opposite way. Parent context does not see any child-context beans. But child sees all parent beans. There is no component scanning, only explicitly created @Beans.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. The child represents the Web and parent the server side and the child can refers/use the beans defined in the parent. Can you post the code what represents the `web.xml` in JavaConfig? there we can see how the `Web Layer Context` and `Application Layer Contex` are referred how main point access

Comment: I do not have the exact code with me, but this is the pattern: http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/developing-web-applications.html

Comment: I gave the "same name" a shot and it did not work...

Comment: You should share the source code about how you are referencing the `Web Layer Context` and `Application Layer Context` through JavaConfig, that file must be the replacement of `web.xml`, without that the community can't go forward to help you.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply renaming the bean declaration method to match with the autowired bean?

```
@Configuration
public class BusinessConfig {
   @Bean 
   public ObjectMapper objectMapper() { return new ObjectMapper() } 
}

@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Will try on monday. But I suppose it should not make a difference, as the default @Autowired mode should by byType